# Add Image in new page to existing PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am new to itext in java. I have an existing pdf of 2 pages. I need to add 2 new pages to it and then add an image to the 3rd page and then add four small rectangles and some text in the 4th page. On searching I got codes for adding new pages and codes for adding images to the existing pdf separately. Column text was used to add text to a new page, I searched for adding image to column text but I cannot find it. `getUnderContent` helped me to add image at the bottom of 2nd page. I want the image to be added in 3rd page. And the 4th page gets more complicated. I add the rectangle and text using `PdfContentByte`. This should be done by creating a new page. Any ideas?

Comment: This is all documented online, but before I answer your question, please show me what you already have. Are you working with `PdfStamper` or are you using `PdfWriter` to create page 3 and 4 and `PdfCopy` to merge page 1 and 2 with pages 3 and 4? There's more than one way to do it, and I need to know your preference (otherwise I'll end up copying my book in an answer and that's not my intention).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I actually tried using `PdfStamper` and added my image at the end of text after 2nd page. I am comfortable with using any methods. I would like to learn more. I haven't used `PdfCopy` yet. I am stuck at how to add a 3rd page.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie  Sorry that should have been "after text at end of 2nd page".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, I assume that you are using `PdfStamper` and that you're able to add an image to an existing page. This is, for instance, done using `getUnderContent()` and its `addImage()` method. Now you need to add an extra page.

In `PdfStamper`, you can use the `insertPage()` method to achieve this:

```
stamper.insertPage(pageNum, rectangle);
```

In this line `pageNum` is an int value indication the page number where you want to insert the new page, and `rectangle` is the size of the page. For instance:

```
stamper.insertPage(reader.getNumberOfPages() + 1, reader.getPageSize(1));
```

Once you have inserted the page, you can get the "over" or "under" content, and add an image to that `PdfContentByte` using the `addImage()` method. You might want to replace `reader.getPageSize(1)` with a `Rectangle` object that corresponds with the dimensions of the image.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution helped. If I get some doubts on inserting 4th page and adding components to it. I will post questions here again.